# запускать функцию перед генерацией pdf в react-pdf плагине react

Tags: reactjs, dompdf, wkhtmltopdf

Я использую два плагина `1react-pdf` для генерации pdf и плагин `html-to-image` для конвертации html в изображение. Но проблема в том, что функция конвертации срабатывает только после создания pdf. Вот эта функция:

```
const downloadImage = async () => {
  return await htmlToImage.toPng(testEl.current, {
    cacheBust: false,
  })
}
```

В этой функции я возвращаю URL, который помещаю в компонент `<Image />`. Например:

```
<Image src={downloadImage} cache={false} />
```

Может быть, поместить функцию в `useEffect`? Пожалуйста, помогите мне с этим.
Вот полный код:

```
import {PDFDownloadLink, Page, Text, View, Document,Image} from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import * as htmlToImage from "html-to-image";

export function CustomComponent() {
  const testEl = useRef();

  const downloadImage = async () => {
    return await htmlToImage.toPng(testEl.current, {
      cacheBust: false,
    });
  };

  const MyDoc = () => (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <View>
          <Image src={downloadImage} cache={false} />
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={testEl} className="test">
        Text
      </div>
      <PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDoc />} fileName="print-test.pdf">
        {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
          loading ? "Loading document..." : "Download now!"
        }
      </PDFDownloadLink>
    </>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

```
const downloadImage = () => {
  return htmlToImage.toPng(testEl.current, {
    cacheBust: false,
  });
};

const MyDoc = () => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <View>
          <Image src={downloadImage} cache={false} />
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};

const asyncF = async () => {
  await downloadImage();
  await MyDoc();
};

useEffect(() => {
  asyncF();
});
```

**EDIT 2**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } from "react";
import { usePDF, Page, Text, View, Document, Image } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import * as htmlToImage from "html-to-image";

export function CustomComponent({}) {

  const downloadImage = async () => {
    return await htmlToImage.toPng(
      document.querySelector(".test"),
      { cacheBust: false }
    );
  };

  const myPdfDocument = (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <View>
          <Image src={downloadImage} cache={false} />
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );

  function triggerDownload(url) {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "test.pdf";
    a.click();
  }

  const [pdfInstance, updatePdfInstance] = usePDF({});
  const [isDownloading, setIsDownloading] = useState(false);

  function initiateDownload() {
    setIsDownloading(true);
    updatePdfInstance(myPdfDocument);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDownloading && pdfInstance.url) {
      triggerDownload(pdfInstance.url);
      setIsDownloading(false);
    }
  }, [isDownloading, pdfInstance.url]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="test">Text</div>
      <button onClick={initiateDownload} disabled={isDownloading}>
        {isDownloading ? "Loading..." : "Download PDF"}
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Возможно вам стоит как то разделить поведение. При нажатии кнопки вызывать htmltoimage, а после завершения ее уже вызвать создание pdf. На сколько я вижу, htmltoimage вызывается из создания pdf.

Comment: @SwaD, я думал уже об этом. Но функционал htmltoimage и создание pdf должен происходит за один клик кнопки. И я не понимаю, почему htmlToImage срабатывает с задержкой. Я уже по всякому пробовал. Может запуск htmltoimage и создание pdf сделать асинхронно?! ... т.е. поочередно

Comment: Вы можете это сделать в один клик. В одной функции вызываете создание картинки, дожидаетесь ответа, затем данные передаете дальше в создание пдф. Т.е. вам надо вызвать создание картинки до изменения состояния компонента, что как раз и приводит к перерисовке данных

Comment: @SwaD, посмотрите. пожалуйста. Я сделал асинхронно. Обновил код, после **EDIT**. Это работает, но так же, с задержкой. Т.е. не асинхронно

Comment: Я в виде ответа оформил, тут не влезет. Не поможет, удалю

Comment: @SwaD, спасибо, но так почему-то вообще пустой pdf печатается. У меня есть другая версия этого функционала. Более гибкая! Сейчас обновлю код.

Comment: @SwaD, обновил вопрос. после **EDIT 2**. Это гибкая версия функционала, и это хорошо работает, но так же, с задержкой. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Может тут получиться как-то сделать поочередно?

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте так. Убрал useEffect и промежуточные сеттеры состояния, что бы компонент был неизменен до окончания работы всех функций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условно...

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
const MyDoc = (image) => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <View>
          <Image src={image} cache={false} />
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};

const asyncF = async () => {
  const img = await downloadImage();
  await MyDoc(img);
};
```

Надо только поэкспериментировать с тем, передавать ли все вернувшееся из функции downloadImage или только .url

---

```
const myPdfDocument = (img) => (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <View>
          <Image src={img} cache={false} />
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );

async function initiateDownload() {
  //setIsDownloading(true);
  const img = await downloadImage(); // берем текущее значение
  const newPDF = myPdfDocument(img); // Создаем пдф
  triggerDownload(newPDF.url); // генерим ссылку
  // тут можно вызвать какой нибудь сеттер для обновления компонента
}
```

Comment: спасибо. касательно второго кода: теперь проблема при скачивании pdf. вот скриншот https://ibb.co/0sr5hTZ

Comment: @rabbit С этими плагинами не работал, поэтому далее уже не подскажу. Надо смотреть, как генерируется изображение в ПДФ. Но идею донес. Надо сначала получить саму картинку, затем уже передавать ее и при этом не перерисовывать компонент.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пытаться дальше.

Comment: @rabbit Посмотрите, может есть аналоги html-to-image для реакта. Или может библиотека генерации пдф умеет сама делать картинки из нужного компонента

Comment: есть плагин html2canvas, но он аналогичен. с ним так же, с задержкой. А react-pdf, к сожалению не умеет генерить картинку.